# form.serialize() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

HTML Code

```
<div id="address" class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
              <form method="post" action="" id="addressDetails">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <textarea id="lAddress" name = 'lAddress' minlength='20' maxlength='100' class="materialize-textarea" class="validate" required length="100"></textarea>
                  <label for="lAddress" data-error="Must be between 20 to 100 Characters">Local Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <textarea id="pAddress" name = 'pAddress' minlength='20' maxlength='100' class="materialize-textarea" class="validate" required length="100"></textarea>
                  <label for="pAddress" data-error="Must be between 20 to 100 Characters">Permanent Address</label>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row center-align">
              <button type="submit" name="submitAddress" form="addressDetails" class="waves-effect waves-light light-blue darken-1 btn updateProfile">Save Address Details</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

JS Code

```
function updateProfile(event) {
    console.log(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    form = $(this).closest('.col s12').find('form');
    console.log($(form));
    $.ajax('profile/updateProfile.php', {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            //console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.updateProfile").on('click', updateProfile);
});
```

I check network AJAX calls using Chrome Debugger. None of the key value pairs are being passed.

There is no errors in Console Logs.

Comment: It would be simpler to bind submit event to the form and then use `this` inside handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector in `closest()` is incorrect. There should be no spaces and both values should be preceded by a `.` to signify a class selector. Try this:

```
var form = $(this).closest('.col.s12').find('form');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1a4bL8xp/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
form = $(this).closest('.col s12').find('form');
```

use

```
form = $(this).parent().closest('.col,.s12').find('form');
```

which matches all the classes and then find the form element

on 4th line of JS code..

Answer (score 0):

Reference the form id

```
form = $('#addressDetails');
```

also you could place an alert on form.Serialize() to see exactly the output it may not match the object your method is expecting.

you could also build the data up by using

```
data:'{lAddress: form.lAddress.val(), pAddress: form.pAddress.val()}'
```

Comment: I have many forms like this so I can't be specific by using id tag and  `form.serialize()` is better than building object separately. Thanks for help :)

Comment: You could add a class to the form which could be common to all your forms and remove the hash. Also have you tried JSON.stringify(form.serialize()) ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(form.serialize())` ? No what does it do ?

Comment: turns an object into a json string which you could alert